# I feel like my code is right, but the execution is still wrong, why?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a digit counter with loop. I am quite sure that my code is right, but the execution is different than what I wanted to. Can someone tell me where I did it wrong?

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long x,y;
    int i;

    cout << "Input X : ";
    cin >> x;

    i=0;
    y=x;

    while(x>0){
        x=x/10;
        i++;
        cout <<i;
    }

    cout <<y<<" is made up of "<<i<<" digits."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So, the execution is :

Input X : 5000

12345000 is made up of 4 digits

Why the ouput is not the same as the input? What is wrong?

Comment: You are printing `i` in each iteration without any separation. Try adding `<< " "` to see how the output changes.

Comment: try this: `    cout << "-done. " << y <<" is made up of "<<i<<" digits."<<endl;
`

Comment: Just step through the code in debugger, or in your head. It should become clear where you get the extra *1234* in output line... Hint, you print it. In your loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `1234` in front of `12345000` is due to you having the `cout <<i` statement at the end of your while loop.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long x,y;
    int i;

    cout << "Input X : ";
    cin >> x;

    i=0;
    y=x;

    while(x>0){
        x=x/10;
        i++;
    }

    cout <<y<<" is made up of "<<i<<" digits."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now your code will run properly